# Round BigDecimal Depending on tenth place value

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Let's say I have a BigDecimal that can be any number of values. If the tenth place value is less than 3 (i.e. 12.2, I want to round down to 12). If the tenth place value is greater than or equal to 3 (i.e 11.3), I want to round the tenth value up to 5, (so the value here would ultimately be 11.5). Does BigDecimal have existing functionality that would allow for easy implementation of this. If not, what are some good ways to achieve this otherwise?

Comment: Hmm, roundDown (val + 0.3)

Comment: What about values that have a 6, 7, 8, or 9 in the 10th decimal place?

Comment: You can first scale down to 10 (which gives you rounded 10 decimal places) and then you can manipulate the UnscaledValue to round to 0 or 5, depending on the last digit. From that, you can create a new BigDecimal with the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own version of BigDecimal and override the `round` method, but this will only help when using that method.  For the rounding that it does naturally (while doing normal math) then there is no easy way to alter its rounding behavior from what it already offers.  If you take a look at the BigDecimal implementation many of the methods that do the rounding are static so you would be unable to override them.

Below is how you can override the `round` method.

```
class MyDecimal extends BigDecimal {

    public MyDecimal(BigInteger val) {
        super(val);
    }

    @Override
    public BigDecimal round(MathContext mc) {

        /* implement your rounding algorithm here*/
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first scale the `BigDecimal` to 10 decimal digits using `setScale()`. Then you can manipulate the last digit of the `unscaledValue()`:

```
public class BigDecimalRounder
{
    public static BigDecimal roundToNearestHalf(BigDecimal value)
    {
        // Scale to 10 decimal digits and get the underlying BigInteger:
        BigInteger digits = value.setScale(10, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).unscaledValue();

        // Act upon the last digit of the BigInteger:
        BigInteger lastDigit = digits.mod(BigInteger.TEN);
        int intDigit = lastDigit.intValue();
        BigInteger newDigit;

        if (intDigit >= 0 && intDigit <= 2)
            newDigit = BigInteger.ZERO;          // round down
        else if (intDigit >= 3 && intDigit <= 7)
            newDigit = BigInteger.valueOf(5);    // round to nearest 5
        else
            newDigit = BigInteger.TEN;           // round up

        // Assemble a new BigInteger, removing the original last digit and 
        // adding the new one (either 0, 5 or 10) 
        BigInteger newValue = digits.subtract(lastDigit).add(newDigit);

        //Assemble a new BigDecimal with the modified digits.
        return new BigDecimal(newValue, 10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BigDecimal mainValue = new BigDecimal("1.2399997990");
        BigDecimal addend = BigDecimal.ONE.movePointLeft(10);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("" + mainValue + " --> " + roundToNearestHalf(mainValue));
            mainValue = mainValue.add(addend);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
1.2399997990 --> 1.2399997990
1.2399997991 --> 1.2399997990
1.2399997992 --> 1.2399997990
1.2399997993 --> 1.2399997995
1.2399997994 --> 1.2399997995
1.2399997995 --> 1.2399997995
1.2399997996 --> 1.2399997995
1.2399997997 --> 1.2399997995
1.2399997998 --> 1.2399998000
1.2399997999 --> 1.2399998000
1.2399998000 --> 1.2399998000
1.2399998001 --> 1.2399998000
```

Comment: Somehow this answer got posted twice, in slightly different versions. This is the one I intended to post.